# How do I install pygame zero in my computer? I am getting error, and cannot find another way

Tags: python, pgzero

I am getting an error installing pygame zero on my computer.

I already have `python 3.6 32 and 64 bit` installed on my Windows system. The 32 bit version was installed with Canopy, I believe. Later, I installed the 64 bit version from the python website itself. Then I tried to install pygame zero (`pip install pgzero`), and here is the message that I get (see 'code'):

> Collecting pgzero
>     Using cached >https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/87/fbb77cfd9c6f2dbe63d09d3e693aa2bcde63995f6f014b3b0bda5d3dbcdd/pgzero-1.2.tar.gz
>      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "", line 1, in 
>        File "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-srz31i\pgzero\setup.py", line 7, in 
>          with open(path, encoding='utf8') as f:
>      TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
>
> ---
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in >c:\users\user1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-srz31i\pgzero\

I also looked up online, and tried to install a wheel `pygame‑1.9.4‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl` (also tried the 64 bit version), but it says this is not the correct version on both files.

How can I install pygame zero?

Comment: You use python3.6, why use the whl of pygame for python3.5?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. The file was pygame‑1.9.4‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl (and pygame‑1.9.4‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl)

Comment: What's the output of `pip --version`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have pip, use this in the command line.

```
pip install pgzero
```

If you do not have pip, but have Linux, do this first.

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Or, if that does not work, then I do not know. Maybe try looking it up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).